# c# select listview item if two listviews contains it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

In my program I have 2 listviews and 1 button.
When I press the button, every listview item in the first listview will be selected in the second listview. The items in the first listview always exist in the second listview, but not the other way around.

I'm having trouble with selecting the items in the second listview. I'm trying to get the index with `IndexOf`.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in firstListView.Items)
{
    int index = secondListView.Items.IndexOf(item);
    secondListView.Items[index].Selected = true;
}
```

I always get an error that `index` is `-1` when I click the button. And I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**SOLUTION**

So what I tried to do here finding an index of an item which belongs to a different listview, and it doesn't work like that. Even though the text in both listviews are the same, the listview items are not identically the same because they are reference types.

I was not able to use the `Text` property because items could have the same text. So the solution I had was putting an unique integer in the `Tag` property for each `ListViewItem`. Since integers are value types, I can use that integer to check whether the `ListViewItem` in the first listview is in the second.

```
// Loop through each item in the first listview
foreach (ListViewItem item1 in firstListView.Items)
{
    // For each item in the first listview, loop through the second listview to find if it's there
    foreach (ListViewItem item2 in secondListView.Items)
    {
        // Check if item1 is identical to item2 by looking at its tag
        if (int.Parse(item1.Tag) == int.Parse(item2.Tag))
        {
            // The item has been found and will be selected!
            item2.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and when debbuging what line is causing error?

Comment: `secondListView.Items[index].Selected = true;` it says value `-1` is invalid

Comment: *I already found a good solution for that...* So you can add your own answer if it is better than existing answers.

Comment: That's not what I meant. But I made your answer the best because you gave me the inspiration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such linq query to select items of the second list which exist in the first list too:

```
var items = from i1 in listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
            from i2 in listView2.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
            where i1.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                    .Where((s, i) => s.Text != i2.SubItems[i].Text).Count() == 0
            select i2;
items.ToList().ForEach(x => { x.Selected = true; });
```

**Note:**
When to try to use `secondListView.Items.IndexOf` method to find an item which belongs to the `firstListView` you can not expect it to find the item. The item you are trying to find its index, doesn't exists in second listview's item collection. You should find items using `Text` property of the item and sub items.

Comment: The `Text` property only gets the text of the first column of the row. And I need to check the whole row because some information could be the same. So `IndexOf` would never work. Now I know it.

Comment: Then you need a better criteria for `where`. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Well the same item obviously cant exist in two different lists.

If the text is the same, then try looking by it:

```
foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in l1.Items)
{
    var item = l2.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(lvi => lvi.Text == listViewItem.Text);
    item.Selected=true;
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (ListViewItem listViewItem in l2.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
    .Where(lvi => l1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Any(lvi2 => lvi.Text == lvi2.Text))
{
     listVieItem.Selected=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IndexOf returns -1 if it cannot find the object passed to it in the list. My guess is that you have an issue with your equality comparison. Do the objects in the lists implement IComparable? Otherwise they may not be finding the items correctly and are reverting to a bad equality comparison. ListViewItem may not be comparing how you expect.

Answer (score 0):

you can try finding the item by text and then get the index like this

```
   foreach (ListViewItem item in firstListView.Items)
        {

            var itm = secondListView.FindItemWithText(item.Text);
            int index = secondListView.Items.IndexOf(itm);
            secondListView.Items[index].Selected = true;
            secondListView.Select();
        }
```

what `FindItemWithText` will do is get the item in `secondListView` which will be of same name as in `firstListView` and `IndexOf` will get the index of item in `secondListView`

**Edit**

This solution is good when you have two lists whose items are same and does not include any repetition in name else if you have two items in `secondListView` with same name `FindItemWithText` will get the first item only.

Comment: There's a slight issue with that, since `FindItemWithText` will find the first item that start with the searchString. So, if the first item is `item100`, and he's looking for `item1` it will find `item100`